# Macro on combo box and Pivot filtering take too long to complete

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that work but it takes too long to complete - 45sec.
What it does is to take a combo box result to update a pivot table filtering.

Do you know what I did wrong and how could I improve it please?:)

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pi As PivotItem
Dim wsChart As Worksheet
Dim wsPivot As Worksheet
Dim SelGeo  As Variant

'turn on automatic update / calculation in the Pivot Table

Set wsChart = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Graph Data")
Set wsPivot = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PCW_pivot")
Set pt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PCW_pivot").PivotTables("Pivot_table1")
Set SelGeo = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Graph Data").Range("SelGeo")

pt.ManualUpdate = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PCW_pivot").PivotTables("Pivot_table1").ClearAllFilters

If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Graph Data").Range("SelGeo") = WW Then
Exit Sub
End If

For Each pi In pt.PivotFields("Geo").PivotItems
Select Case pi.Name
    Case [SelGeo]
        pi.Visible = True
        Case Else
        pi.Visible = False
    End Select
Next pi


'turn on automatic update / calculation in the Pivot Table

pt.ManualUpdate = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why use square brackets in `Case [SelGeo]`? That is potentially causing a bug, and if not, it's ambiguous whether `[SelGeo]` gets interpreted as a foreign identifier referring to the `SelGeo` variable, or forwarded to `Application.Evaluate("SelGeo")`, which presumably evaluates to some `#NAME?` error value.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - the `SelGeo` is a name reference to the cell that convert the combo-box into a name. So basically `SelGeo` = `$E$3` = "Japan" - I needed to create it as a variant so the pivot understand I want to force it or do you think I could use the `$E$3` more efficiently?

Comment: `[SelGeo]` is shorthand for `Application.Evaluate("SelGeo")`. This is confusing, especially since there's a variable named `SelGeo` that's in-scope. Make the code unambiguous by making it say what it does, *and do what it says*. `theSheet.Names("SelGeo").RefersToRange.Value` (or `theWorkbook.Names("SelGeo").RefersToRange.Value`, depending on the name's scope) is much clearer, and completely unambiguous. Or, simply use the `SelGeo` variable you've got, instead of re-grabbing that same range off the worksheet again.

Comment: I see your point, it can be indeed confusing, what would you recommend to replace then the `case [SelGeo]` ?:)

Comment: You already have a local variable `SelGeo` that is referring to that range: just use that variable instead! Remove the square brackets, and make an explicit member call instead of an implicit one - `Case SelGeo.Value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try turning off calculation. Also, consider testing for the negative of your test... this allows for code that can run from start to end naturally without needed to `Exit Sub` in the middle

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PCW_pivot").PivotTables("Pivot_table1").ClearAllFilters

If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Graph Data").Range("SelGeo") <> WW Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        For Each Pi In pt.PivotFields("Geo").PivotItems
            Select Case Pi.Name
                Case [SelGeo]
                    Pi.Visible = True
                    Case Else
                    Pi.Visible = False
                End Select
        Next Pi
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @urdearboy - it seems to work however the automatic calculation end in manual, not automatic - any way to adjust this. The time was improved to 20sec

Comment: Change it to `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`

Comment: many thanks - I still get one error now - when running the code, it says : Unable to set the visible property of the PivotItem class? line `Pi.Visible = False ` any idea why?

Comment: You have to have at least one value selected so if you are trying to turn off the only selected value you will get problems.